# pass results of one query into another in SQL

Tags: sql, join

I have two queries:

```
SELECT g.id FROM "group" g INNER JOIN group_role gr on g.id = gr.group_fk
INNER JOIN role_details rd on rd.group_role_fk = gr.id
INNER JOIN mandate m on m.role_details_fk = rd.id where m.id = x
```

and

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, g.name, g.id
FROM person p INNER JOIN position pos on p.id = pos.person_fk
INNER JOIN role_details rd on rd.id = pos.role_details_fk
INNER JOIN group_role gr on gr.id = rd.group_role_fk
INNER JOIN "group" g on g.id = gr.group_fk
WHERE g.id = y
```

I would like to be able to pass g.id into the second query so that for a given "x", I get p.id, p.name, g.name, g.id returned. How can I do this? Can it be done with more joins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest your queries like this, called Sub Queries, assumed both queries are working and the subquery only returns a single value.

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, g.name, g.id
FROM person p INNER JOIN position pos on p.id = pos.person_fk
INNER JOIN role_details rd on rd.id = pos.role_details_fk
INNER JOIN group_role gr on gr.id = rd.group_role_fk
INNER JOIN "group" g on g.id = gr.group_fk
WHERE g.id = (SELECT g.id FROM "group" g INNER JOIN group_role gr on g.id = gr.group_fk
INNER JOIN role_details rd on rd.group_role_fk = gr.id
INNER JOIN mandate m on m.role_details_fk = rd.id where m.id = x)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use a subquery like

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, g.name, g.id
FROM person p INNER JOIN position pos on p.id = pos.person_fk
INNER JOIN role_details rd on rd.id = pos.role_details_fk
INNER JOIN group_role gr on gr.id = rd.group_role_fk
INNER JOIN "group" g on g.id = gr.group_fk
WHERE g.id IN (SELECT g2.id FROM "group" g2 INNER JOIN group_role gr on g2.id = gr.group_fk
INNER JOIN role_details rd on rd.group_role_fk = gr.id
INNER JOIN mandate m on m.role_details_fk = rd.id where m.id = x)
```

Take care to use different aliases in the subquery unless you want to address the exact row you are looking at in the outer query.

To avoid the subquery you can reformulate the query using more joins - possibly joining the same table more than once using different aliases. Depending on the DBMS this might gain you some performance.